# How can I escape a parameter within a Mixin?

Tags: sass, mixins

```
=elements($a: 1, $b: 2, $c: 3)
```

If I want to declare value for `$b` or `$b and $c` only, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use named arguments

[DEMO](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/9a37021e1ede3e83b7f6253970c75a79)

```
=els($a: 1, $b: 2, $c: 3)
  height: $a + px
  width: #{$b}px
  content: $c

.cool
  +els

.things
  +els($a: 100)

.stuff
  +els($c: 29)

.other
  +els($c: 29, $b: 54)
```

Comment: Perfect!!
I was looking for it.